# create objects files depending on the name of target

Tags: linux, makefile

Is it possible to create objects files in makefile depending on the name of the target?

something like

```
all : gsm gsm_db

if make gsm
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

if make gsm_db
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_DB) $< -o $@
```

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it as simple as `TARGET1: object1.o` and `TARGET2: object2.o`?

Comment: no, the name of the object files would be same both the times, but they would be build using different libraries depending on the name of the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ifneq "$(filter gsm_db, $(MAKECMDGOALS))" ""
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_DB) $< -o $@
else
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
endif
```

Comment: what are variables like MAKECMDGOALS called ? how do i search for them ?

Comment: Everything is in the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Quick-Reference.html